# If $v_1, \ldots, v_p$ are chosen uniformly within a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, how to find $E(Vol(v_1, \ldots, v_n)^{2a}))$ for positive $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_p$ are chosen independently and uniformly within a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to find:

$$
E\left(\left[Vol(v_1, \ldots, v_n)^{2a}\right]\right)
$$ for positive integer $a$.

That is, I'd like to find the expectation of the volume of the vectors taken to the power of $2a$, where $a$ is a positive integer. Is there an easy way to do this with integral jacobians?

Comment: Do you need exact expressions or would a (good) estimate be enough?

Comment: Can you explain what is the "volume of the vectors"

Comment: @PhoemueX I am trying to find an exact form, from which I was told there should be, but I'm not exactly sure how to see it.